# how to convert date format in C#

Tags: c#

i need to convert a date from

"01/30/2011"  -> "2011-01-30"

How can i convert in c#? I tried with .Tostring(yyyy-MM-dd). It dint work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happened? Error? Wrong format?  Also, you need to put quotes around the format.

Answer (score 5):

If your input is a `string` (rather than a `DateTime`), that's why your `ToString` call didn't work. You simply need to parse it first, then format the resulting value:

```
// I'll be honest: I don't really know if this is the "right" choice or not.
// Maybe someone else can weigh in on that.
IFormatProvider formatProvider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("01/30/2011", "MM/dd/yyyy", formatProvider);
string converted = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse your string into a `DateTime` type and then format it the way you want.

Here is a code snippet:

```
string d = "01/30/2011";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(s);
string output = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",dt);
```

Comment: Or you can always do a regex if you don't care about what date it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple sample too:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     textBox1.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason why it's inside the event Click of a button?

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", DateTime.Parse("01/30/2011"));
```